# How to store escaped "\u" Unicodes mixed with unicodes shorter and longer than "U+FFFF" from a string separately into an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, unicode

Let's say you have a string like this:

```
unicodes = ["\ua7a8\ua7a9\ud800\udf30\ud800\udf31\ud800\udf32\ud800\udf33\ud800\udf34\ud800\udf35\ud800\udf36\ud800\udf37\ud800\udf38\ud800\udf39\ud800\udf3a\ud800\udf3b\ud800\udf3c\ud800\udf3d"]
```

And I want to put every unicode separately into an array.

so that it looks like this `["\ua7a8","\ua7a9","\ud800\udf30"]`

What I've tried was this:

```
unicodes = ["\ua7a8\ua7a9\ud800\udf30\ud800\udf31\ud800\udf32\ud800\udf33\ud800\udf34\ud800\udf35\ud800\udf36\ud800\udf37\ud800\udf38\ud800\udf39\ud800\udf3a\ud800\udf3b\ud800\udf3c\ud800\udf3d"]
var collectedUnicodes = []

for (let i=0; i < unicodes.length; i++) {
    collectedUnicodes = collectedUnicodes.concat(unicodes[i].split(""))
}

console.log(collectedUnicodes)
```

Which returns this:

```
['Ꞩ', 'ꞩ', '\uD800', '\uDF30', '\uD800', '\uDF31', '\uD800', '\uDF32', '\uD800', '\uDF33', '\uD800', '\uDF34', '\uD800', '\uDF35', '\uD800', '\uDF36', '\uD800', '\uDF37', '\uD800', '\uDF38', '\uD800', '\uDF39', '\uD800', '\uDF3A', '\uD800', '\uDF3B', '\uD800', '\uDF3C', '\uD800', '\uDF3D']
```

The problem is that it destroys those unicodes that are longer than 4 digits. They were separated into two `\u`.

Because `\uD800` and `\uDF37` together is one Unicode. And I want to achieve that it gtes put into one array element together. And it might be possible that there are unicodes split up like that, which could be starting with `\uF` instead of `\uD`.

What's the proper way on doing that?

Comment: For historical reasons, JavaScript does not handle correctly characters that are encoded using 4 bytes in UTF-16 ([see yours](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%EA%9E%A8%EA%9E%A9%F0%90%8C%B0%F0%90%8C%B1%F0%90%8C%B2%F0%90%8C%B3%F0%90%8C%B4%F0%90%8C%B5%F0%90%8C%B6%F0%90%8C%B7%F0%90%8C%B8%F0%90%8C%B9%F0%90%8C%BA%F0%90%8C%BB%F0%90%8C%BC%F0%90%8C%BD)). But, what exactly are you trying to do with them?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález at the end I want to display the "U+" unicode. I think the actual unicode from one of those ``\uD`` ones can be calculated together to get the "U+" code out of it.

Comment: @MisterJojo no it is ment to be like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.codePointAt()` to generate the Unicode code point at a given position, `.toString(16)` to get the hexadecimal representation and either the spread operator (`[...input]`) or a for+of loop to split individual characters in a fully Unicode-aware way:

```js
const input = "\ua7a8\ua7a9\ud800\udf30\ud800\udf31\ud800\udf32\ud800\udf33\ud800\udf34\ud800\udf35\ud800\udf36\ud800\udf37\ud800\udf38\ud800\udf39\ud800\udf3a\ud800\udf3b\ud800\udf3c\ud800\udf3d";

let output = [];
for (const character of input) {
   output.push("U+" + character.codePointAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase());
}

console.log(input, output.join(''));
```

[Encoding for reference](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%EA%9E%A8%EA%9E%A9%F0%90%8C%B0%F0%90%8C%B1%F0%90%8C%B2%F0%90%8C%B3%F0%90%8C%B4%F0%90%8C%B5%F0%90%8C%B6%F0%90%8C%B7%F0%90%8C%B8%F0%90%8C%B9%F0%90%8C%BA%F0%90%8C%BB%F0%90%8C%BC%F0%90%8C%BD).

(You may not need the proxy array, I didn't really investigate further).

Comment: When you input this ``\u00a1\u2030\u00ad\u00b7\u20b4\u2260\u00bf\u00d7\u00d8\u00de\u04bb\u00f0\u00f8\u00fe\u0391\u0392``

do you know why one of those characters is empty when printing character out?

Comment: I also got an output that said "Selection deleted" but only if I use with for loop instead of "for of"

Comment: Which one is empty? How can you possibly get "Selection deleted" with that code?

Comment: I modified the for of part with a for loop and integer, then I got the Selection deleted. Apparently the for of and the for loop is not the same thing?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear enough. If you access individual characters in a string using square brackets you'll get higher planes Unicode characters split. Such characters didn't exist when JavaScript was created, that's why you need modern language features.